# In play 2.0.3, I have 'sets' of images that I want to categorise and put in the database when I start the server

Tags: java, database, webserver, playframework-2.0

I need a site for my work as goldsmith and since I have 'some' programming experience I thought I'd do it myself, it would just be a site to display some images of my work and basic contact info.

What I'm trying to do is basically this:

I put my images/renders of jewels in a folder structure like this

```
- public
- - images
- - - creations
- - - - JewelSet1
- - - - - Jewel1
- - - - - - img1
- - - - - - img2
- - - - - - img3
- - - - - Jewel2
- - - - JewelSet2
- - - - - Jewel3
- - javascripts
- - stylesheets
```

And when the `public static Result index()` method is called for the first time, it should search trough public/images/creations and categorise the folders into three objects I made, namely: CreationSet, Image and Creation, which are basically:

```
package models;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Image extends Model{
    @Id
    public String id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public BufferedImage img = null;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String desc;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Creation extends Model {
    @Id
    public String id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String desc;

    public List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

    public void addImage(int priority, Image img){
        images.add(priority, img);
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class CreationSet extends Model {
    @Id
    public String id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String desc;

    public List<Creation> creations = new ArrayList<Creation>();

    public void addCreations(int priority, Creation creation){
        creations.add(priority, creation);
    }
}
```

Then go trough the lists of `CreationSet`s and generate the right HTML in the html-templates

Is this the right way to go? Or how should I do it?

Comment: "I thought that before I start writing code I should ask whether the way I thought of would even work" - nope, generally you should hit tutorials first, write code second, ask on SO when stuck. This site is a good problem solving engine; less so a security blanket.

Comment: Well yeah, I followed quite some tutorials already and read up on the play wiki. But couldn't find much on this subject

Comment: Well, no, you won't find a step-by-step guide to every single thing you need to do. Figuring this out is kind of what programmers are there for. For what it's worth, my first instinct for this would've been uploading images using some sort of backend admin interface that Play! can hopefully automatically generate. That said, it's not necessarily the "right" option, you might already have some other workflow generating this directory structure. Or you might not. Etc. (As you can see, vaguely discussing design ideas can take forever, which is why it's a bad form of SO question.)

Comment: Of course not, and a step-by-step guide isn't what I'm looking for, all I want is some confirmation that the direction I'm going with this is possible. I'm more then willingly to figure the rest out myself

Comment: Everything is *possible* if you try hard enough. Whether it's a good idea is something it's more or less impossible for someone unfamiliar with the context of your project; it's just not a question specific enough for SO. Now, it is possible to say that something is a terrible idea, but "scan a file hierarchy into an explicit data structure" is a fairly mundane technique and thus a valid approach. So the only answer I can imagine you'd get is "no, what you're trying to do isn't completely nonsensical"; this doesn't add helpful content to SO, which is why security blanket questions are bad.

Comment: Alright I get it, but to be honest you just gave me the answer I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW, that could should be in the [Global](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaGlobal) object. Not on some index page.

You can override the start method which will be called when starting your application. All fixture data in the examples of the Play folder, are done in the Global object.

I would have done it otherwise. The big problem with local assets is you are depending on an existing filesystem, relative/absolute paths and you will probably end up messing between local/production etc.

The truly stateless system would be to setup an external filesystem to manage assets. Amazon S3 for example. In that way, if you deploy a new instance of your Play application, your static assets will still be coherent.

**Edit 1 :** And last point, if by *generating the right html* you mean generating Java/Scala code that will be compiled, don't. Compilation times are pretty long, plus you are going to make a 
mess of it. Nobody except you will ever be able to understand your code.

**Edit 2 :** And one last point (promised) : as a goldsmith you must be aware that tools have different objectives and even if you have a hammer, you cannot solve all problems with it. Let me say as a programmer, that Play is really a very beautiful tool with many advantages but it might not be the most adequate *hammer* in  your case.